# Delete duplicates records from DB Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to eliminate duplicates from a table but the query I'm using deletes the entire database and not the duplicates, can you tell me why and what I can do? Thank you very much in advance to the whole community..

This is code

```
$ids = EsitiAudit::
groupBy(['master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea', 'frequency_audit', 'data_audit', 'esito', 'employee', 'eseg_riass', 'categoria'])->get(['id'])->all();

EsitiAudit::whereNotIN('id', $ids)->delete();
```

Comment: well id is not in groupBy which will cause issues on some databases, ex : `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'id' isn't in GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing complete elements to the `->delete()` query, try this instead:

```
$esitiAudits = EsitiAudit::groupBy(['master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea', 'frequency_audit', 'data_audit', 'esito', 'employee', 'eseg_riass', 'categoria'])->get(['id']);

$ids = $esitiAudits->pluck('id')->toArray();

EsitiAudit::whereNotIn('id', $ids)->delete();
```

Pick just the ids from the elements on the query and then delete the files.

Comment: So doesn't the `pluck()` extract values from the `id` column, and it doesn't take into account the grouping of columns. Then shouldn't the first line be `select()->groupBy()->get()` and then you can use the `pluck()`. I am understanding this wrong?

Comment: @Adi Im not retrieving the ID from the table column to pass it to `pluck()`, the IDs are generated by the groups of elements made by `groupBy`, so each group will have a unique ID, then `whereNotIn()` ensures that one row of the duplicated are retained, by eliminating the one with the lower ID number.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for clarification.

Comment: You can use `::select()->groupBy()->get()` but that will be like another entire line of code with all the elements again, and select the lowest `id` to pass it into `pluck()`, but I think it's cleaner this way.

Comment: No worries i think i understood how your solution works too since they are many ways of doing, so upvoted. It's just confusing sometimes as to how pluck works with groupby function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = EsitiAudit::select('id')
->groupBy(['master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea', 'frequency_audit', 'data_audit', 'esito', 'employee', 'eseg_riass', 'categoria'])
->havingRaw('COUNT(id) > 1')
->get();

$idsToDelete = $ids->pluck('id')->toArray();

EsitiAudit::whereNotIn('id', $idsToDelete)->delete();
```

1. we have to check whether the id is present multiple times or not by checking the count.
2. Next, we use pluck('id') to extract the id values from the result.
3. we use whereNotIn with the extracted idsToDelete to delete the duplicate rows that are not in the list of IDs to keep.

Comment: That way you'll end deleting every row that doesn't have a duplicated `id`, and keep just 1 of the duplicated ones. On a normal use, where the `id` is set to `auto_increment`, you'll never have duplicated ID on the table. That will just empty the entire table...